# Mostrar emoticons com botão independente do teclado

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no qual criei um botão que gostaria que fizesse a mesma função de mostrar os *emoticons* do teclado. Essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 btnMostrarEmoticons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mostra emoticons
        }
    });
```

Existe algum método que mostra os emoticons com botão independente do teclado?

Answer (score 2):

[Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts) [parece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968557/how-to-make-a-emoticon-keyboard?noredirect=1&lq=1) [que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030450/custom-keyboard-for-emoticons-in-android?rq=1) [não](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408088/in-app-emoji-keyboard).

Mas você pode tentar uma [biblioteca](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) de emojis que se assemelha muito com a entrada de emoji do teclado para atingir esse objetivo.